# How do I simplify google sheets formula to achieve the goal I've specified?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I keep getting an error for this code. I know there has to be an easier way to get the same result but I can't figure it out. I'm currently working on a premade character sheet document for google sheets that already had a lot of stuff done for it but is missing a few things. This function is meant to show one of the weapons damage dice from the data sheet I made for it depending on a selection they make in V29 which is a dropdown. It is then supposed to print out the ability modifier added to it dependin on the selection in AG29

=IF(V29=Data!W2,Data!X2,IF(V29=Data!W3,Data!X3,IF(V29=Data!W4,Data!X4,IF(V29=Data!W5,Data!X5,IF(V29=Data!W6,Data!X6,IF(V29=Data!W7,Data!X7,IF(V29=Data!W8,Data!X8,IF(V29=Data!W9,Data!X9,IF(V29=Data!W10,Data!X10,IF(V29=Data!W11,Data!X11,IF(V29=Data!W12,Data!X12,IF(V29=Data!W13,Data!X13,IF(V29=Data!W14,Data!X14,IF(V29=Data!W15,Data!X15,IF(V29=Data!W16,Data!X16,IF(V29=Data!W17,Data!X17,IF(V29=Data!W18,Data!X18,IF(V29=Data!W19,Data!X19,IF(V29=Data!W20,Data!X20,IF(V29=Data!W21,Data!X21,IF(V29=Data!W22,Data!X22,IF(V29=Data!W23,Data!X23,IF(V29=Data!W24,Data!X24,IF(V29=Data!W25,Data!X25,IF(V29=Data!W26,Data!X26,IF(V29=Data!W27,Data!X27,IF(V29=Data!W28,Data!X28,IF(V29=Data!W29,Data!X29,IF(V29=Data!W30,Data!X30,IF(V29=Data!W31,Data!X31,IF(V29=Data!W32,Data!X32,IF(V29=Data!W33,Data!X33,IF(V29=Data!W34,Data!X34,IF(V29=Data!W35,Data!X35,IF(V29=Data!W36,Data!X36,IF(V29=Data!W37,Data!X37,IF(V29=Data!W38,Data!X38,"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))""&IF(AG29=B9,StrMod,IF(AG29=B10,DexMod,IF(AG29=B11,ConMod,IF(AG29=B12,IntMod,IF(AG29=B13,WisMod,IF(AG29=B14,ChaMod,""))))))

I'm just struggling to look for an easier way to have it print values from a column of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even simpler solution that will work without modifying the existing sheet:

```
=
XLOOKUP(V29,Data!W2:W38,Data!X2:X38,"")
&
" - "
&
IFNA(
  IFS(
    AG29=B9,”StrMod”, 
    AG29=B10,”DexMod”, 
    AG29=B11,”ConMod”, 
    AG29=B12,”IntMod”, 
    AG29=B13,”WisMod”, 
    AG29=B14,”ChaMod”
  ),””
)
```

The line returns and indents are not required, just adding to show the formula structure more legibly than one long line.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and explanation, definitely helped me understand the XLOOKUP function better. It works perfectly now, this is gonna make D&D so much easier for the new players I bring in.

Comment: Glad I could help—have fun!